# Marking data labels on outliers in 3D scatter plot

Tags: r, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have a tab separated dataset that looks like this

```
Labels  t1  t2  t3
gene1   0.000000E+00    0.000000E+00    1.138501E-01
gene2   0.000000E+00    0.000000E+00    9.550272E-02
gene3   0.000000E+00    1.851936E-02    1.019907E-01
gene4   8.212816E-02    0.000000E+00    6.570984E+00
gene5   1.282434E-01    0.000000E+00    6.240799E+00
gene6   2.918929E-01    8.453281E-01    3.387610E+00
gene7   0.000000E+00    1.923038E-01    0.000000E+00
gene8   1.135057E+00    0.000000E+00    2.491100E+00
gene9   7.935625E-01    1.070320E-01    2.439292E+00
gene10  5.046790E+00    0.000000E+00    2.459273E+00
gene11  3.293614E-01    0.000000E+00    2.380152E+00
gene12  0.000000E+00    0.000000E+00    1.474757E-01
gene13  0.000000E+00    0.000000E+00    1.521591E-01
gene14  0.000000E+00    9.968809E-02    8.387166E-01
gene15  0.000000E+00    1.065761E-01    0.000000E+00
```

What I want: is to get a 3d scatterplot with labels of outliers, like this:

[image]

What I have done: in R

I have actually read each column individually like this:

```
library("scatterplot3d")
temp<-read.table("tempdata.txt", header=T)
scatterplot3d(temp1$t1, temp1$t2, temp1$t3)
```

What I want: is that the labels of outliers should be displayed atleast for the top 250 or how can I get these labels of top 250 outliers in a variable for further analysis.

Could anyone please guide me through this in R.

The solution in python are also welcome.

Comment: How do you classify outliers? Top 250 in zz/xx/yy value? Or in Euclidean distance from origin/mean/some point?

Comment: You can find the largest values of vectors by using `sort(temp1$t1, TRUE)[1:250]`

Comment: what about the labels? although I figured it out how to get it but I need to filter my data based on the value in last column, for example if I have a two times value of gene13 it should sort it and givethe out put based on the value in last column.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. Do you want the outliers of the t3 column and their corresponding labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plotting 250 labels into a plot is not a good choice since it will make the plot impossible to read. If you want to label outliers in your plot these should be far away from the rest of your data points to easily identify them uniquely. You can however save the largest 250 zz values and their corresponding labels in a matrix for further analysis. I would do something like this:

```
# Create some random data
library("scatterplot3d")
temp1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(900), ncol=3))
temp1$labels <- c("gen1", "gen2", "gen3")
colnames(temp1) <- c("t1", "t2", "t3", "labels")

# get the outliers
zz.outlier <- sort(temp1$t3, TRUE)[1:5]
ix <- which(temp1$t3 %in% zz.outlier)
outlier.matrix <- temp1[ix, ]

# create the plot and mark the points
sd3 <- scatterplot3d(temp1$t1, temp1$t2, temp1$t3)
sd3$points3d(temp1$t1[ix],temp1$t2[ix],temp1$t2[ix], col="red")
text(sd3$xyz.convert(temp1$t1[ix],temp1$t2[ix],temp1$t2[ix]), 
     labels=temp1$labels[ix])
```

Here I also marked the points with a red color. This would allow you to mark a slightly larger amount of outliers than using text labels while still keeping the plot fairly accessible. It will however also fail if there are multiple points in close proximity.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is in matplotlib:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot, cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

data = np.genfromtxt('genes.txt', usecols=range(1,4))
N = len(data)
nout = N/4   # top 25% in magnitude
outliers = np.argsort(np.sqrt(np.sum(data**2, 1)))[-nout:]
outlies = np.zeros(N)
outlies[outliers] = 1   # now an array of 0 or 1, depending on whether an outlier

fig = pyplot.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.scatter(*data.T, c=cm.jet(outlies)) # color by whether outlies.
pyplot.show()
```

Here it is, red are far from origin, blue nearby:
[image: genes]

Comment: Thanks, can you please also add a line to get the list of these outliers.

Comment: @Angelo `outliers` is already a the list of outliers.  You can add a line to `print outliers` if you wish.  Your dataset counts from `gene1` but outliers counts from `0`.  So, you'd actually want `print outliers + 1`